# How to get Directory name in msbuild configuration file?

Tags: msbuild

Here is the simple code which I am using. Which gets all the folders in the directory and then give me the Folder name.

```
<TestProjectFolderPath Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(`$(SolutionDir)`,`*.Tests`))" />
<TestProjectFolderNames Include="@(TestProjectFolderPath->'$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName(`$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName(`%(Identity)`))`)',' ')" />
```

But in TestProjectFolderNames [System.IO.Path] functions are not getting evaluated and returned as just string eg:

```
 $([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName(C:\Some.Unit.Tests)))
```

I need help to understand the correct syntax to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using property functions on Item Metadata while transforming an Item is not supported I think (maybe it is in the latest MSBuild version but I cannot test that right now). As a workaround add new Metadata yourself and because it acts like a Property things work out ok for recent MSBuild versions:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <TestProjectFolderPath Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(`$(SolutionDir)`,`*.Tests`))" />
  <TestProjectFolderPath>
    <FolderName>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName(`%(Identity)`))</FolderName>
  </TestProjectFolderPath>
</ItemGroup>
<Message Text="@(TestProjectFolderPath->'%(FolderName)', ' ')" />
```

*edit* see comments, according to Sherry for older MSBuild versions the equivalent Item code is:

```
<TestProjectFolderPath Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories($(SolutionDir),*.Tests))">
  <FolderName>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName(%(Identity)))</FolderName>
</TestProjectFolderPath>
```

I left out GetDirectoryName because it makes little sense calling that on the result of GetFileName.

Comment: It gives me this error "The required attribute "Include" is empty or missing from the element <TestProjectFolderPath>"

Comment: Ok I solved it my mistake:

 <TestProjectFolderPath Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories(`$(SolutionDir)`,`*.Tests`))">
      <FolderName>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName(`%(Identity)`))</FolderName>
    </TestProjectFolderPath>

Comment: hmm, what version of MSbuild do you use? The code you show doesn't work for me, no message gets printed. While the code I have worked for both MSBuild 12.0 and 15.0.

Comment: Ohh interesting :: 

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.7.2556.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: So the above version , the solution you gave did not work and and it complained about the Include . And the one which I was suggesting works in 15 as well. Just tested it. Anyway you gave a close enough answer so thank you

Comment: Ok I don't have older MSBuild versions to test, but if the code you gave in your second comment works ok I'll add that to the answer?